# Jpa Criteria filter range dates in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, jpa

I need to filter by a date range and I have created a class using jpa specifications, but it doesn't filter the data and returns all the rows. This is my class

```
public class SolicitudBetweenFecInFecfin implements Specification<Solicitud> {
    
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        
        private final long fechaIn;
        
        
        private final long fechaFin;
        
        public SolicitudBetweenFecInFecfin(long fechaIn, long fechaFin) {
            
            this.fechaIn = fechaIn;
            this.fechaFin = fechaFin;
            
            
        }
    
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Solicitud> solicitud, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(fechaIn==0 || fechaFin==0) { //carga todos los datos inicialmente sin filtrar
                return criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));
                
            }
            
            
        
            /*final ParameterExpression<LocalDate> fecIn = criteriaBuilder.parameter(LocalDate.class,fechaIn.toString());
            final ParameterExpression<LocalDate> fecFin = criteriaBuilder.parameter(LocalDate.class,fechaFin.toString());
            System.out.println("Fecha in parseada"+fecIn.toString());*/
            System.out.println("Fec solicitud db "+solicitud.get(Solicitud_.FEC_SOLICITUD).getModel().getBindableType());
            
            Predicate between = criteriaBuilder.between(solicitud.get("fecsolicitud"), new Date(fechaIn), new Date(fechaFin));
            
            return between;
            //return criteriaBuilder.and(startsAfterBegin, endsBeforeEnd);
        }
    
    }
```

I don't get any error but it doesn't filter the data. This is the result obtained in Postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAaAN.png)